# after updating NDK I'm having these errors

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): armeabi

Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.
```

I was just avoiding cleaning or rebuilding the whole project until I got the latest NDK update and the problem re-emerged.

How to solve this problem?
Any advice?

Comment: Check the supported ABIs arm-v7a, x86, x86-64 and etc

Comment: I didn't do anything. I just updated it and opened the old project.     
For a half day, I didn't understand. What's the reason?

Comment: If you have `APP_ABI=armeabi` in **Application.mk** file, replace this with `APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: You did not, they depreciated some ABIs, so we need to migrate to the new version